# HTML Div Center Align in internet explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I Have Written The Following Code . It Is Showing Absolutely Fine In Mozilla and Chrome . But IN Internet Explorer , it is not center aligned and display at the left side . Here Is The Code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>ProgramEngine Website Registration</title>
<style type="text/css">
div#login
{
background-color:#f1f1f1;
width: 510px;
height: 1024px;
border: 1px solid grey;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="login"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

So Can AnyBody Suggest Me What is the Problem And How To Overcome It.

Comment: Which version of internet explorer are you referring to? This works fine for me in IE7+ and I can't see any obvious problems that your code may be causing

Comment: Which version of IE are you testing in? It seems to work fine my end in IE7+.

Comment: Works fine in IE http://jsfiddle.net/L2Cwk/

Comment: I'm having idea. can you use jquery?

Comment: @KarSho, there is no need - this works fine in IE. I suspect that you have some CSS elsewhere that is resetting your declaration.

Comment: This should work in IE8. http://jsfiddle.net/FZ42J/ Are you testing in the correct setup of IE8 ?

Comment: Actually that is not working , and that is all the code , see This image [link](http://s13.postimage.org/5vfk6qcs7/2013_01_04_16_26_21.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use jquery for good solution.

[See this Link](http://jsfiddle.net/NpTsa/)

```
$(document).ready( function(e){    
        var screen = $('body').width();
        screen -= 51;  //51 is width of div
        screen /= 2;
        $('#login').offset({top:0,left:screen});
    });​
```

if you need use top in offset value.

Here, browser can't makes problem.

Answer (score 3):

Are you using correct DOCTYPE? Without the DOCTYPE, IE automatically goes into Quirks render mode - this is your problem, probably.

Comment: what DOCTYPE IE (all version) support?

Comment: Use for example HTML 5 Doctype <!DOCTYPE html> .